# "Share via Twiiter" posting to developer account instead of prompting for login

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, android-twitter

In my application I want to implement "share via Twitter" functionality where in user will login to twitter(if not already logged in) and then can share their tweet. With the following code that I got from the internet, I am able to post a tweet from my app but it is never asking to login. Instead it is posting a tweet to the account from where I created consumer key and secret key.

Can any one please guide me where am I going wrong?

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(twitter_consumer_key);
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(twitter_secret_key);              

String CALLBACK_URI = "http://www.google.com";
String ACCESS_TOKEN = "***************";
String ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "****************";
AccessToken ac = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
Log.d("robin", "caught");
// Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(twitter_consumer_key, twitter_secret_key);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(ac);
Log.d("sayfsdem", "caught");

try {
    twitter4j.Status status = twitter.updateStatus(tweetText);
    Log.d("status", status.toString());
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Log.d("final", "caught");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    Log.d("userName", twitter.getScreenName());
    // Log.d("password",twitter.getFavorites()());
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.d("illesayem", "caught");
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    Log.d("fdfds", "caught");
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code it will be usefull for you to send image in twitter

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-send-image-to-twitpic-from-android/

Answer (score 0):

You should not hardcode the `ACCESS_TOKEN` and `ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET` in your code as the values are the credentials for your own account. Instead, when the user open your app for the first time, you should ask them to login, save the access token and the token secret returned by the login page, and use them in subsequent Twitter API calls.